# .NET Remoting serialize lambda expression based delegate

Tags: .net, remoting

I want to subscribe to an event on a `MarshalByRefObject` that lives in a separate process. I tried:

```
remoteObject.Progress += (sender, args) => { };
```

This throws an exception because the lambda is not serializable:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Type '...+<>c__DisplayClass3_0' in Assembly '...' is not marked as serializable.'

Clearly, I cannot mark this compiler generated type `[Serializable]`. How can I subscribe to an event using Remoting?

Comment: Not as elegant as a lambda, but what about creating a simple, serializable class containing the target method?

Comment: @Alejandro thanks, I crafted a solution based on your suggestion. If someone has a better solution I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Alejandro in the comments a possible workaround is to create a class. I constructed this solution:

```
class DelegateAdapter<T> : MarshalByRefObject
{
    Action<T> localHandler;

    public DelegateAdapter(Action<T> localHandler)
    {
        this.localHandler = localHandler;
    }

    public void RemoteHandler(T value) => localHandler(value);
}
```

And it can be used like this:

```
[Serializable]
delegate void MyCustomDelegate(SomeType arg);

MyCustomDelegate dlg = new DelegateAdapter<SomeType>(arg => { ... }).RemoteHandler;
```

The delegate is serializable. It's target is a `MarshalByRefObject` in the calling process that can do whatever you want.